# Javascript select dropdown content below moves

Tags: javascript

I wanted to adjust the height of the dropdown select menu, and set the size to 10 on dropdown. However, this causes all the content below the select menu to go down by 10 lines. I want the option in the select menu to be displayed on the foreground or just that it does not cause the content below it to move.

```
<select id="particle" onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;'>
<option value="angryVillager">angryVillager</option>
<option value="barrier">barrier</option>
<option value="blockcrack">blockcrack</option>
<option value="blockdust">blockdust</option>
<option value="bubble">bubble</option>
<option value="cloud">cloud</option>
<option value="crit">crit</option>
<option value="damageIndicator">damageIndicator</option>
<option value="depthsuspend">depthsuspend</option>
<option value="dragonbreath">dragonbreath</option>
<option value="dripLava">dripLava</option>
<option value="dripWater">dripWater</option>
<option value="droplet">droplet</option>
<option value="enchantmenttable">enchantmenttable</option>
<option value="endRod">endRod</option>
<option value="explode">explode</option>
<option value="fallingdust">fallingdust</option>
<option value="fireworksSpark">fireworksSpark</option>
<option value="flame">flame</option>
<option value="footstep">footstep</option>
<option value="happyVillager">happyVillager</option>
<option value="heart">heart</option>
<option value="hugeexplosion">hugeexplosion</option>
<option value="iconcrack">iconcrack</option>
```

Comment: Also, when I click an option in the select menu, the size goes not back to 1 row, only when I click outside the select menu

Comment: [GlobalEventHandlers.onblur (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur)

Comment: @AlanLarimer You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be to put the position of the selector as `absolute`, and next shift all the elements below the element with the css 
property `top`. You can also use a hidden element to shift down all the elements below the `select` (see the Ufuk Akoguz answer).

```
#particle {
   position: absolute;
}

/* Stuff below the selector */

#title {
   padding-top: 45px;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3c9kysv) for an example.

**Edit 1**

To close the selector when user click on a option just add at the onclick callback.

```
<select id="particle" onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' onclick='this.size=1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help

```css
    div{
    border: none;
   height: 29px;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 268px;
   }
```

```html
<div>
<select id="particle" onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;'>
<option value="angryVillager">angryVillager</option>
<option value="barrier">barrier</option>
<option value="blockcrack">blockcrack</option>
<option value="blockdust">blockdust</option>
<option value="bubble">bubble</option>
<option value="cloud">cloud</option>
<option value="crit">crit</option>
<option value="damageIndicator">damageIndicator</option>
<option value="depthsuspend">depthsuspend</option>
<option value="dragonbreath">dragonbreath</option>
<option value="dripLava">dripLava</option>
<option value="dripWater">dripWater</option>
<option value="droplet">droplet</option>
<option value="enchantmenttable">enchantmenttable</option>
<option value="endRod">endRod</option>
<option value="explode">explode</option>
<option value="fallingdust">fallingdust</option>
<option value="fireworksSpark">fireworksSpark</option>
<option value="flame">flame</option>
<option value="footstep">footstep</option>
<option value="happyVillager">happyVillager</option>
<option value="heart">heart</option>
<option value="hugeexplosion">hugeexplosion</option>
<option value="iconcrack">iconcrack</option>
</select>
</div>
<p>something</p>
```